# Set dropdown item selected MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have multiple dropdown list for same select list in look and want to set dropdown item selected as per loop.

How can I set specific one item of dropdown list selected in mvc dropdownlist.

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Html.DropDownList` method takes multiple parameters, one of them being a `List<SelectListItem>`. The individual instance of the `SelectListItem` is where you set the `Selected` property:

```
var item = new SelectListItem() {

    Selected = /* condition */,

    Value = "Some Value",
    Text = "Some Text"
};
```

**Alternatively:**

Create a `SelectList` collection that exposes the `SelectedValue` property:

```
Model.YourSelectList = new SelectList(items /* List<SelectListItem> */,
                                      "Value",
                                      "Text",
                                      37 /* selected value */);
```

Comment: @{
                                    ViewData["Sectors"] = new SelectList(Model.SectorList, "MainCategoryId", "CatName", "37");
                                }
                                @Html.DropDownList("SectorId" + i, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Sectors"], "-- Select --", new { @class = "inputbox-small" })

Comment: And?! I hope you didn't set them all to `true`. That would defeat the purpose of setting the `Selected` property ...

Comment: No, my value for each dropdown will be different which is "37" so Select List will be same but selected will be different in loop. Please correct me if I am wrong in my code.

Comment: Yes, I am constructing it. Any other way where I can easily set selected like optional label parameter?

Answer (score 2):

When building the SelectList, you can set the selected item on construction using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460123.aspx

Or you can set it on an individual `SelectListItem` via it's `Selected` property ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected.aspx ) and use the single-parameter constructor of the select list, or pass it straight to the DropDownList method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML helper ListBoxFor.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.MyPropertyId, Model.MySelectList)
```

To build the list of items, you can use the MultiSelectList.  For example, in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Get a collection of all product id's that should be selected.
    int[] productIds = _service.GetSomeProductIds();

    // Make a new select list with multiple selected items.
    ViewBag.List = new MultiSelectList(
        _service.Products, 
        "Id",                   // Name of the value field
        "Name",                 // Name of the display text field
         productIds );          // list of selected product ids

    return View();
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ProductIds, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.List)
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC method to bind custom list to dropdownlist and select item dynamically
if you need more details ,comment below

Create Section

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
   list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SALE", Value = "SAL" });
   list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "PURCHASE", Value = "PUR" });
}

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SaleOrPurchase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">           
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SaleOrPurchase, list, "-- Select Status --", new {@class= "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SaleOrPurchase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT Section

```
     List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
     list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SALE", Value = "SAL" });
     list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "PURCHASE", Value = "PUR" });

     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myCollection = list.AsEnumerable();

     ViewBag.SaleOrPurchase = new SelectList(myCollection, "Value", "Text", transactionTbl.SaleOrPurchase.ToString().Trim());
```